# Linearization of a nonlinear third order ODE and stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

I would like to know if the following differential equation ($\alpha,\beta,\gamma,d,\Lambda,w$ are constants)

$x'''(t)=\frac{1}{24 (3 \alpha -\beta )}\frac{x(t)^{-3 w-2}}{x'(t)} \left(36 \alpha  x(t)^{3 w+2} x''(t)^2-12 \beta  x(t)^{3 w+2} x''(t)^2+108 \alpha  x(t)^{3 w} x'(t)^4-36 \beta  x(t)^{3 w} x'(t)^4-6 \gamma  x(t)^{3 w+2} x'(t)^2-72 \alpha  x(t)^{3 w+1} x'(t)^2 x''(t)+24 \beta  x(t)^{3 w+1} x'(t)^2 x''(t)+d x(t)+2 \gamma  \Lambda  x(t)^{3 w+4}\right)$

where prime denotes derivative with respect to $t$ of the function $x(t)$, can be linearized in some way in order to obtain information about the stability of the possible solutions. I have tried the standard approach of calling $x'(t)=A$, $x''(t)=B$ and expanding in Taylor series, but I can't get rid of the nonlinearities.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

After transforming to the canonical form

$$
\cases{\dot x_1 = x_2\\ \dot x_2 = x_3\\ \dot x_3 = f(x_1.x_2,x_3)}
$$

you can follow doing $\delta_i = x_i-x^0_i$ and

$$
\cases{
\dot \delta_1 = \delta_2\\
\dot \delta_2 = \delta_3\\
\dot \delta_3 = f(x^0_1,x^0_2,x^0_3)+\sum_k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}|_{(x^0_1,x^0_2,x^0_3)}\delta_k
}
$$

Here $x^0_k = x^0_k(t)$

Example

$$
x'''(t)=\frac{\left(c_1x''(t)^2+c_2 x(t)^{-2} x'(t)^4\right)}{x'(t)} 
$$

in the canonical form it gives

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\ 
\dot x_2 = x_3\\ 
\dot x_3 = \frac{\left(c_1x_3(t)^2+c_2 x_1(t)^{-2} x_2(t)^4\right)}{x_2(t)} 
}
$$

then

$$
\cases{
\dot \delta_1 = \delta_2\\
\dot \delta_2 = \delta_3\\
\dot \delta_3 = \frac{\left(c_1x_3^0(t)^2+c_2 x_1^0(t)^{-2} x_2^ 0(t)^4\right)}{x_2^0(t)} -\frac{c_2x_2^0(t)^3}{x_1^0(t)^2}\delta_1 + \left(\frac{3c_2x_2^0(t)^2}{x_1^0(t)}-\frac{c_1x_3^0(t)^2}{x_2^0(t)^2}\right)\delta_2+\frac{2c_1x_3^0(t)}{x_2^0(t)}\delta_3
}
$$

The functions $x_k^0(t)$ are all known so the resulting system is linear in $\delta_k$

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment. That's exactly what I was refering to when I said "standard approach", but the nonlinearities are present in the system. Concretely, after doing this procedure I can't write a matrix and check its eigenvalues because the resultant equation for $\dot\delta_3$ is not linear on $\delta_i$. I can put in the original post the resulting equation if you want to check it. Any idea?

Comment: Please. Have a look at the included example.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right, I was confused. Even with the extra inhomogeneous term, the stability can be checked with the standard method of studying the associated matrix eigenvalues? Thanks.

Comment: The resulting system is linear but unfortunately not LTI.

Comment: Yeah, then I think the procedure to determine the stability has some problems. Do you know a way to do that?